# Getting a List<T> from Matching two Seperate List<T>s

Tags: c#, list, optimization

All, I would like to know if there is a better way of getting a `List<T>` of matching values from two seperate `List<T>`s.

The way I would do this currently if I wanted to find all the items in string list `itemList<string>` (a distinct list) that were in another list `bankList<string>` (also distinct so the returned list is also distinct - no duplicates) would be

```
List<string> matchingList = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in itemList)
    if (bankList.Contains(s))
        matchingList.Add(s);
```

Is there a better and/or quicker way of doing this?

Extension: I appreciate the question has been answered (and this is taking advantage) but out of interest, would the best way of getting the negation (that is, those items *not in* `bankList<string>`) be

```
List<string> interList = new List<string>();
interList = itemList.Intersect(bankList).ToList<string>();
matchingList = itemList.Except(interList).ToList<string>();
```

or in this case would it be back to

```
List<string> matchingList = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in itemList)
    if (!bankList.Contains(s))
        matchingList.Add(s);
```

I think in this case it interestingly could be the latter?

Comment: See my edit for your second question. In general, you should ask a new question rather than editing a new question in. Once you have accepted an answer to your question, most people aren't going to pay attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a **clearer** way to do this:

```
var matchingList = itemList.Intersect(bankList).ToList();
```

Moreover, it will be faster, because it won't be `O(n^2)`. Right now, you're traversing the `bankList` for every item in `itemList`. Instead, you should build a `HashSet` from `itemList`, and then check for containment in that `HashSet` as you walk `bankList`. That's exactly what [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) will do.

So, you win on both fronts: performance and readability.

> would the best way of getting the negation (that is, those items not in bankList) be

Just say

```
var except = itemList.Except(bankList).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually this also will be quicker since `Intersect` is using a Hashset internally - OP's approach on the other hand is O(n^2)

Comment: +1 Nice! Not seen this before, I am currently getting to the stage with C# now that I am gradually learning lots of 'hidden' (most of the time better) ways to do things. Thanks for your time.